# Mi Bot de discord hecho en Python no responde

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy haciendo un bot de discord con python y logro activar el bot(me sale conectado), pero al momento de hablarle no me retorna nada. Mi codigo

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = os.getenv('MI TOKEN')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") #Prefijo del bot

@bot.command(name="s") #Funcion que realizara la suma entre dos numeros enteros
async def sumar(ctx, num1,num2):
    response = int(num1)+int(num2)
    await ctx.send(response)

client.run("MI TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solución

Sucede que estás creando dos objetos de conexión, pero solo inicias uno (client). El que inicias no tiene la extensión de comandos, por lo tanto no funciona.

No es necesario llamar a discord.Client, alcanza con llamar a commands.Bot, que según [la documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot) es una clase derivada de discord.Client. En palabras simples, incluye todo lo que incluye discord.Client y más.

En conclusión, la solución es iniciar solo una conexión. Y por lo que veo conviene que esa conexion sea commands.Bot.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") #Prefijo del bot

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command(name="s") #Funcion que realizara la suma entre dos numeros enteros
async def sumar(ctx, num1,num2):
    response = int(num1)+int(num2)
    await ctx.send(response)

bot.run("tu token")
```

#### Advertencia

Discord.py está descontinuado oficialmente desde el 28 de agosto del 2021 :c
Te recomiendo pasarte a otro modulo o lenguaje de programación. Mientras buscaba el mensaje que dejó el creador sobre la discontinuación, encontré un modulo que parece plantearse como la continuación de discord.py: https://pythonrepo.com/repo/nextcord-nextcord

Comment: Gracias, me funciono!

Comment: Como se puede ver en el [GitHub](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tags) y en el [Changelog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new.html?highlight=changelog) de `discord.py`, la librería se sigue actualizando. Si bien es verdad que estuvo 1 año sin actualizarse como advirtió Dante, el desarrollo continúo en Agosto de 2022 y sigue hasta hoy, haciéndolo una alternativa válida. `nextcord` también es otra alternativa válida, que también sigue actualizándose a día de hoy.